# Error Plugin SoupUI in Rational Application Developer 8.0

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, ibm-rad

I am trying to install SoupUI in IBM Rational Application Developer 8.0.

I go to "Help and Install New Software" and check "Available Software Site". I add the location "http://www.soapui.org/eclipse/update/" and then select "OK". In the name and version box I see, there is no site selected. When I type the url in the "Work with" box and add this url, I am getting the error:

> "No software site found at http://www.soapui.org/eclipse/update/. Do
>   you wish to edit the location?"

How can I plugin SoupUI to RAD? Please help.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you contact the admins of the [website](http://www.soapui.org/soapui-for-ide/eclipse/eclipse-plugin.html) ... it appears that the update site that they indicate is not available.